# How do I change ngStyle dynamically?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-universal, ng-style

I need to change multiple styles when some variable changes.

I can use something like:

```
[style.left]="isMenuShown ? '0px' : '-100vw'"
```

it works fine, but I wish to change multiply styles.

And I try to use ngStyle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_blond97/xgm8becr/12/):

```
<div [ngStyle]="styleList">...</div>
```

And in controller something like:

```
if (this.isDefaultStyle) {
    this.styleList = {'background' : 'green'};
  } else {
    this.styleList = {'background' : 'red'};
  }
```

It seems like it works, but when I inspect it with `f12` I see

> ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"

Thereby question is: does it mean it is not working correctly? And if yes what is the correct way for me to change ngStyle dynamically?

Comment: When you inspect it with f12 you see style="background: green none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]". It is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) instead `ngStyle`

```
<div [ngClass]="{isMenuShown ? 'show' : 'hide'}">...</div>
```

in css:

```
.show{multi style when show menu}
.hide{multi style when hide menu}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ngClass** instead of **ngStyle** as you need to change multiple styles.

> Here is an example:

```
    <some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

    <some-element [ngClass]="{'class1': var1===1, 'class2': var1===2, 'class3': var1===3}">...</some-element>

    <some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

> Description:

Inside ngClass object: The key is a class name and the value is condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function to accomplish the dynamic variations.

```
<div [ngStyle]="getStyleList()">...</div>
```

In controller

```
function getStyleList(){
 if (this.isDefaultStyle) {
       return {'background' : 'green'};
  } else {
      return {'background' : 'red'};
  }
}
```

Comment: How much time it may be called per minute? I don't like funcs in templates because sometimes it starts to be called multiply times

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle like this

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background' : isDefaultStyle ? 'green' : 'red'}">...</div>
```